# Code Signing Error with iPhone Configuration utility for in-house distribution

Tags: iphone

We have an Enterprise license to distribute our app in house.  From that account on developer.apple.com, we generated a provisioning profile.  On some people's machines, the provisioning profile works and they are able to install the app.  On others, they get,

> "Could not install application on device.  Error: A signed resource
>   has been added, modified, or deleted."

Are there particular things I can check to see why it works on some people's machines and not on others?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this on PC (Windows based) systems? 
if so check out the filenames, Mac OS X is more flexible than Windows in terms of the characters you can use in filenames.

Comment: so do you get the error on Macs as well? have you tried to narrow down the problem to wether it happens on certain iDevices, or certain computers. i.e if a problematic iDevice is used with another computer will it work? etc

Comment: Yes I have problems on both types of machines. Like my coworker's PC it works fine to install the app with the utility.  My Mac used to work, but no longer does.  My PC does not work to install the app.